# How to authenticate the Microsoft stream user account in server side

Tags: asp.net-mvc, video, video-streaming, streaming

I am newbie to Mvc and UI framework. Now I am working on asp.net mvc application and in one case we need to show a video from Microsoft stream. Now what happened is before streaming the video it asks the users to authenticate then only can view the video. So is there any that can we have streaming login credentials at web.config and automatically signed in to play the videos automatically without asking any user credentials.

Thanks in Advance..!!

Comment: If you return a stream, then you should only validate the user credentials the first time the user requests the stream.. What kind of authentication are you using, is it your own implementation or have you used something like asp.net identity?

Comment: @Martin M, We are using OWIN based authentication in asp.net mvc app. Once the user is logged in we are playing the video from Microsoft stream. What we need is only the authorised user can see the video. But in Microsoft stream it asks the Microsoft sign in but not all my user not have a microsoft account to share with. So how to deal with the scenario